# How, if possible, can I use variadic templates to make a function that prints multiple std::vectors of any type side by side?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to write a function printV() that takes some number of vectors (probably less than six) of any built-in type printable with cout, passed as const reference and prints them side by side, so that compareV(v1, v2, v3) would produce the output:

```
v1[1], v2[1], v3[1]  
v1[2], v2[2], v3[3]
v1[3], v2[3], v3[3]
```

Here is the function I'm using to print a single vector:

```
template <typename T>
void printV(const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I would like to adapt this function to print multiple vectors, side by side. However, I don't know if it's possible to do something like:

```
template <typename... T>
void printV(const std::vector<T>... &vec)
{
     //code that expands (vec...) into vec1, vec2, vec3 etc. the part I'm unsure about

     for(int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++)// the size of the first vector will be the same as the other two
     {
          std::cout << i << ": " << vec1.at(i) << ", " << vec2.at(i) << ", " << vec3.at(i) << std::endl;
     }
}
```

I would have to use some sort of utility function and an intermediate string variable to get around the fact that the pramaters cannot be accessed together in the same scope.
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/)  microsoft documentation article, as well as section 3.4.4 of *"The C++ Programming Language"* Recommend using recursion to seperate the first argument from all of those after it and making an overload of the function for the case with no parameters:

```
// From Section 3.4.4 of "The C++ Programming Language"
template<typename T, typename ... Tail>
void f(T head, Tail... tail)
{
g(head); // do something to head
f(tail...); // try again with tail
}
void f() { } // do nothing
```

which would prevent access to multiple parameters in a single scope. How might I get around this?
Any suggestions or general advice is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
template <typename firstT, typename... T>
void printV(const std::vector<firstT>& first, const std::vector<T>& ... vec)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) 
     {
          std::cout << i << ": " << first.at(i);
          ( (std::cout << ' ' << vec.at(i)), ... );
          std::cout << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Live: https://godbolt.org/z/dq5P64

Comment: Maybe add a comment that this throws if any vectors that are not `first` are shorter then `first`.

Comment: Be paranoid, wrap the cout stream in a void cast before using operator comma.  Also variardic std min with initializer lists could make the "unequal array" case less throwy.  Finally, you should template the allocator.